# Jackson. Deserialeze lists with different generic types

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization

I want deserialize List<Contact> with custom deserialezer using jackson library.
List<Document> and List<Good> should deserialize by default.

There is my class

```
public class Application implements Serializable {
    //other fields

    private List<Document> documents;
    private List<Contact> contacts;
    private List<Good> goods;
}
```

But I can't change it to add annotations. So I use mixin

```
public abstract class ApplicationMixin {
    @JsonProperty("contactId")
    private List<Contact> contacts;
}
```

Custom deserializer:

```
@JsonComponent
public class ContactsDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<List<Contact>> {
    @Override
    public List<Contact> deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException {
        List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<>();

        //some logic

       return contacts;
   }
}
```

And during deserialization all lists try to use this custom deserializer.
But I want it only for contacts.
What can I do for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The observed behavior is caused by the [type erasure](https://www.baeldung.com/java-type-erasure). On runtime, Jackson cannot tell the difference between `List<Contact>`, `List<Document>` or any other List, so it applies the ContactsDeserializer to all of them. You will need to be more precise about what the deserializer should be applied to.

You can try the following:

1. remove `@JsonComponent` annotation from the `ContactsDeserializer`
2. in the `ApplicationMixin`, add `@JsonDeserialize(using = ContactsDeserializer.class)` to the `contacts` field.

```java
public abstract class ApplicationMixin {
    @JsonProperty("contactId")
    @JsonDeserialize(using = ContactsDeserializer.class)
    private List<Contact> contacts;
}
```

Alternatively, you might consider creating a custom deserializer for the `Contact` class instead of the `List<Contact>`. If it's possible depends on the input JSON format.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mafor!
I've tried adding annotation `@JsonDeserialize` before too. But it didn't work.
And when i removed `@JsonComponent`, it started working.
I used this in my previous deserializer when I really needed it and left it here without thinking